# How to use a column's name in an expr() instead of direct value for add date in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to add the value of a column (`add_value`) which is based on seconds, to a timestamp column (`start_date`).

```
+-----------------------+----------+
|       start_date      | add_value|
+-----------------------+----------+
|2022-09-05 00:00:01.394|  6.001   |
+-----------------------+----------+
```

Using the below code for direct value works fine.

```
(col('start_date') + expr('INTERVAL 6.001 seconds')).alias("end_date")
```

But replacing it with the column's name has an error.

```
(col('start_date') + expr('INTERVAL add_value seconds')).alias("end_date")
```

error:

> Syntax error at or near 'seconds': extra input 'seconds'(line 1, pos
> 22)
>
> == SQL == INTERVAL add_value seconds
> ----------------------^^^

How should I use the column's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INTERVAL` doesn't let you use values from a column. But an easy approach can be that you cast the timestamp as `double` and then add the decimal seconds. Convert the resulting `double` value to a timestamp to get the desired format.

```py
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('2022-09-05 00:00:01.394', 6.001)]).toDF(['start_date', 'add_value']). \
    withColumn('start_date', func.to_timestamp('start_date')). \
    withColumn('start_date_added_value', 
               (func.col('start_date').cast('double') + func.col('add_value')).cast('timestamp')
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+
# |start_date             |add_value|start_date_added_value |
# +-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+
# |2022-09-05 00:00:01.394|6.001    |2022-09-05 00:00:07.395|
# +-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

To create intervals using existing columns you can concatenate `'interval' + add_value + 'seconds'` and cast the resulting string into `INTERVAL` type. Then you can add it to timestamp `start_date`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
    'end_date',
    F.col('start_date') + F.format_string('interval %s seconds', 'add_value').cast('interval')
).show()

# +-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+
# |start_date             |add_value|end_date               |
# +-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+
# |2022-09-05 00:00:01.394|6.001    |2022-09-05 00:00:07.395|
# +-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+
```